# Data duplicate in listview while fetching from firebase android studio

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

when I fetch data from firebase in listview data repeat itself how to stop duplication anybody help me, please...

```java
databaseReference.child("Conversation")
    .child(current_token)
    .child(user_token)
    .addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
      @Override
      public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        String msgs = null;
        for (DataSnapshot snapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
          ChatMessage chatmessages = snapshot.getValue(ChatMessage.class);
          msgs = chatmessages.getMessageText();
          Log.e("chk", "" + msgs);
          arrayList.add(new chatmessages(msgs)); //here is duplication
        }

        chat = new Chat(getApplicationContext(), arrayList);
        chatlistView.setAdapter(chat);
      }

      @Override
      public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

      }
    });
}
```

Comment: Below link can help you find the better approach. https://stackoverflow.com/a/47618418/7155466

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have created `arrayList` in the class instead of `onDataChange` method.

Therefore the list of data is growing with duplicate data.
You could make following

1) Declare `arrayList` in `onDataChange`

2) call `arrayList.clear()` before foreach. In this case you should instead

```
chat = new Chat(getApplicationContext(), arrayList);
chatlistView.setAdapter(chat);
```

call

```
chatlistView.notifyDatasetChanged();
```

and initialize it previously

Answer (score 2):

clear arraylist before adding new list from firebase or initialise list again i.e.

```
arraylist = new ArrayList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Override hashCode() and equals() methods in chatmessages class so every chatmessages is unique.